# Running a specific version of a function dependent on condition?

Tags: c++

I'm not great at explaining things, so I'm gonna try my best too.
In C++, is there anyway to make a version of a function to run dependent on a certain condition? I understand that if I do virtual functions, I can do something like the following:

```
virtual int thisFunction()

thisFunction(int, string)

thisFunction(int,int)
```

That's just from memory, but I was wondering if I could do this dependent on a certain condition? E.G. if you had a function to display a menu, make it change dependent on the permission level? Just something that isn't in an `if` statement.

Comment: Why not an if statement?

Comment: I could, it just looks messier. Its just curiosity, because just writing something like: displayMenu() looks better than if(permission==1) displayMenu1 else if(permission == 2) displayMenu2()

Comment: Not an `if`? `switch` OK? But seriously, `if` or `switch`  is probably the best way to do this. Following that, consider an array of function pointers. Then your code looks something like `displayfuncs[permission](arguments)`

Comment: @TheHowe: So make another function `displayMenu(int)` that has the `if` statement within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two good ways come to mind.

With a switch statement:

```
switch(permission)
{
    case 1: displayMenu1();break;
    case 2: displayMenu2();break;
    case 3: displayMenu3();break;
};
```

With an array of function pointers:

```
typedef void (*displayfunc)() ;
displayfunc displayfuncs[] =
{
    displayMenu1,
    displayMenu2,
    displayMenu3
};
```

usage:

```
 displayfuncs[permissions]();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use an if statement or case statements in the method calling the function, you can pass the permission level (or whatever other value your condition relies on) as an argument to the function, and write logic in the function to deal with whatever the permission level is.

You can deal with different function argument types through overloading, where you simply define the function multiple times as you did, with the only change being the types of the arguments.